# Why do I have to invoke function DataContext ExecuteMethodCall twice

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am using linq to sql to execute SPs, but getting this issue for a few of the SPs. I have to execute the function ExecuteMethodCall twice to get the result. The first call does not even go to SQL Server. I used SQL Profiler to check if the SP was executed, but I get this in profiler:

RPC:Completed  exec sp_reset_connection

The subsequent call to ExecuteMethodCall actually executes the SP and gets data.

```
[Function(Name="dbo.Example_SP_To_Get_List")]
[ResultType(typeof(Example_SP_To_Get_List_getResult1))]
[ResultType(typeof(Example_SP_To_Get_List_getResult2))]
public IMultipleResults Example_SP_To_Get_List([Parameter(Name="SEARCH", DbType="VarChar(50)")] string sEARCH, [Parameter(Name="PAGE", DbType="VarChar(1)")] string pAGE, [Parameter(Name="ACTIVEFILTER", DbType="VarChar(4)")] string aCTIVEFILTER)
{
    //first invocation, returns nothing, does not even call the SP (SQL Profiler does not show the sp call)
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), sEARCH, pAGE, aCTIVEFILTER);

    //second time, it executes the SP and returns the result
    result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), sEARCH, pAGE, aCTIVEFILTER);
    return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

Please help me find why this is happening to few SPs, while others work fine.

Comment: So you're saying that if you comment out the first `ExecuteMethodCall`, that method will return nothing?

Comment: @TyCobb yes, it returns nothing if I comment the first line.

Comment: Show us the code for `ExecuteMethodCall`.

Comment: @TyCobb, it is a system function defined in DataContext class, so I don`t have code for this function.

Comment: Based on the very first line in the documentation for `ExecuteMethodCall`: "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." I would imagine there are other better ways to call a stored proc.

Comment: @TyCobb, I am not using this function directly, MS SQLMetal generated this code for me and it is the same code that is generated behind the dbml file (for SPs). During troubleshooting this issue I found that it works if I execute this call twice (for some SPs), but I'll figure out what is the root cause

Comment: @TyCobb, would you please suggest a better way to call SPs using linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a SP returns multiple result sets, then the caller function must fetch all result sets in sequence. In above case, the SP returned two result sets and I was only fetching the second result set.
Using following code resolves the issue:

```
var spResults = dbLayer.Example_SP_To_Get_List();

var result1 = spResults.GetResult<Example_SP_To_Get_List_getResult1>().ToList(); 
var result2 = spResults.GetResult<Example_SP_To_Get_List_getResult2>().ToList();
```

Not sure if it is the best way, but it resolved my issue.